# Java class declaration with angular bracket

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am new to java, and came across with the below syntax while reading a code.

```
public class APIRequest<T extends APINode> {
}
```

What does this syntax mean? It is different from the regular class declaration syntax.

Comment: Google Java generics.

Comment: read this documentation http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/92/generics#t=201705211135560450356

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Answer (score 1):

`<T extends APINode>` means that `T` has to be subclass of `APINode`.

About generics:

```
public class Chest<T> {

    private T t;

    public Chest(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    T getContent() {
        return t;
    }

}
```

`<T>` means here that you can create parameterized type of `Chest` which will contain object with `T` type. Without generic type you have to create new class for each type you want to store, so instead of:

```
Integer a = 10;
Chest<Integer> chestWithInteger = new Chest<>(a);

Double b = 10.0d;
Chest<Double> chestWithDouble = new Chest<>(b);
```

You have to create two classes `DoubleChest` and `IntegerChest`.

Comment: The OP seams to have problems with the brackets at all, so please could you explain that in more detail?

Comment: Here is the link that is using this construct.   https://github.com/facebook/facebook-java-ads-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/com/facebook/ads/sdk/APIRequest.java

Answer (score 0):

This is generics. You can read more here [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)